# Template argument deduction/substitution failed - std::find()

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, find

I'm not using templates.
I've looked through some of the related posts, but couldn't really find anything exactly like my issue - though I'm sure they are and I just don't understand them.

I have the following code:

```
#pragma once

// define logging levels
#define logging 1

// standard includes
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
vector<struct sockaddr_in> activeNodes;

-------
bool
RoutingManager::ActivateNewNode(struct sockaddr_in newNode)
{
    find(activeNodes.begin(), activeNodes.end(), newNode) != activeNodes.end())
    [..]
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get a thousand errors, e.g.,:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:276:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from globals.h:9,
                 from manager.h:3,
                 from manager.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:194:17: note:   ‘sockaddr_in’ is not derived from ‘const std::_List_iterator<_Tp>’
    if (*__first == __val)
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/list:63:0,
                 from manager.h:8,
                 from manager.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1602:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
     operator==(const list<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const list<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1602:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from globals.h:9,
                 from manager.h:3,
                 from manager.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:194:17: note:   ‘sockaddr_in’ is not derived from ‘const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>’
    if (*__first == __val)
                 ^
make: *** [build/manager.o] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define non-member overloads for the equality operators, like so:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
bool operator == (const sockaddr_in &lhs, const sockaddr_in& rhs) {
      return lhs.sin_family == rhs.sin_family 
        && lhs.sin_port == rhs.sin_port
        && lhs.sin_addr.s_addr == rhs.sin_addr.s_addr
        && lhs.sin_zero == rhs.sin_zero;
}
bool operator != (const sockaddr_in &lhs, const sockaddr_in& rhs) {
      return !(lhs == rhs);
}

int main()
{
    vector<sockaddr_in> activeNodes;
    sockaddr_in newNode;
    std::find(activeNodes.begin(), activeNodes.end(), newNode);
}
```

I considered using `strcmp` but they're unsigned char, so I'm not sure whether or not the equality will fail.

Answer (score 4):

First, you really should have

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

because this is the header that defines the `sockaddr_in` structure. Second, the error messages you are getting are due to the fact that `std::find` doesn't know how to compare `struct sockaddr_in` objects for equality. To fix this, define an overload for `operator==`.